# Is this output valid or a compiler bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string s = {123};
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Why does this program print `{` as an output? Is it a bug in the underlying lexer that it only prints the preceeding `{`?

I compiled this with g++ 4.8.1 (with no errors or warnings). MSVC doesn't compile this complaining that `string` isn't an aggregate type.

Comment: 123 is the ASCII code for {

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736282/what-is-this-smiley-with-beard-expression

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are list-initializing a string with an array of characters. `123` is the [ASCII code of `{`](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif). There is no compiler bug.

The constructor you are invoking is the initalizer-list constructor of `std::string` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) for a reference), as specified by paragraph 21.4.2/15 of the C++11 Standard:

> ```
> basic_string(std::initializer_list<CharT> init, 
>              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Same as `basic_string(il.begin(), il.end(), a)`.

MSVC does not support list-initialization, which is why you are getting the message complaining about the fact that `string` is not an aggregate.