# C++11 lambdas as default function arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a C+11 function that takes a callable as an argument, and I'd like to have that argument default to a no-op function. This is my best attempt so far:

```
const std::function<void()> noop= [](){};
void f( int x, int y, std::function<void()> fn= noop ) { /* ... */ }
```

I'm wondering whether the standard libraries provide a "noop" std function for me, or do I need to write my own as I have above? I'm also wondering if there's a way to avoid explicitly naming the "noop" function. For example:

```
void f( int x, int y, std::function<void()> fn= [](){} ) { /* ... */ }
```

won't compile (in Visual Studio 2012 Update 3), nor will:

```
void f( int x, int y, std::function<void()> fn= std::function<void()>([](){}) ) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: +1: Good question, but what about this little fix? `void f(int x, int y){ f(x, y, [](){}); }` (where `void f(int, int, std::function<void()>)` is your original function without optional parameter)

Comment: Works in g++ 4.7.2 BTW.

Comment: You should not make your `noop` a `std::function`, make it `auto noop = []{};`.  I suspect VS2012 is in the wrong here.  And the canonical noop is `[]{}` -- save `()`!  Or `<:]{%>` (the clown noop) for maximal amusement.

Comment: @Yakk: That's a [*bearded* lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15736282/500104). Get your terminology right! :P

Comment: @Xeo know how hard it is to *search* for that on the internet?

Comment: @JesseGood Bah, deleting my misinformation.

Comment: @Zeta I agree that I could manually overload the function, but I think I'd prefer a named "noop" variable as a default argument (less typing, less error-prone)

Comment: It will compile in MSV2015 BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering whether the standard libraries provide a "noop" std function for me, or do I need to write my own as I have above?

No, there are no default noop functions. In this case, you have to create your own (like you did with noop functor object).