# Boolean lambdas?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

How come this code compiles???

[**LIVE CODE**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2124fca96368051)

```
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    auto lambda1 = []{};
    auto lambda2 = []{};

    if(lambda1 && lambda2) {
        std::cout << "BOOLEAN LAMBDAS!!!" << std::endl;
    }

    if(lambda1 || lambda2) {
        std::cout << "BOOLEAN LAMBDAS AGAIN FTW!!!" << std::endl;
    }

    bool b1 = lambda1;
    bool b2 = lambda2;

    std::cout << b1 << ", " << b2 << std::endl;
}
```

Boolean lambdas! (Or boolambdas, if you will... *shies away*)

How come this works? Is this another GCC bug? If not, is this standard?

Comment: I'm sorry, but why exactly does it surprise you?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Well, I see lambdas and booleans as two totally different things.

Comment: will  `int * t = new int(0); int * t1 = new int(0); bool b1 = t; bool b2 = t1; std::cout << b1 << b2;` also be surprising then?)

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Not like that between lambdas and booleans. `:)`

Comment: Is there now going to be a storm of self-answered questions about lambda's conversion to function pointer? "Whaaaat? I can compare a lambda to a zero?? What does `&*[]{}` mean?" and so on?

Comment: @avakar You foresaw something great! But let's not talk too much about it... they might hear and make your prediction come true...

Comment: @avakar: Just wait until they [combine them with digraphs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15736282/500104)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that it is standard!

If you refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18889029/1619294)<sup>[1]</sup>, **non-capturing** lambdas are convertible to function pointers. And it turns out again that function pointers, being pointers themselves, are implicitly convertible to `bool`!

> #### 4.12 Boolean conversions [conv.bool]
>
> <sup>1</sup> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
>   prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false;
>   any other value is converted to true. A prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of
>   type bool; the resulting value is false.

To give a supporting proof that the conversion to function pointer is what makes all of this happen, I've tried doing the same thing with capturing lambdas. Then "can't convert to `bool`" errors are generated.

[**LIVE CODE**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d7ae912d917c57f)

```
int main() {
    int i;
    auto lambda = [i]{};

    bool b = lambda;

    if(lambda) {}
}
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub>Which, honestly, gave me the idea to write this.</sub>

Comment: Isn't the point of asking a question... to expect an answer from other people?