# Printing the smiley-with-beard lambda expression

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, digraphs

I tried printing the [smiley-with-beard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736282/what-is-this-smiley-with-beard-expression) lambda expression

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << <:]{%>; // smile!
    return 0;
}
```

but it printed

```
1
```

instead. How?

Comment: put <:]{%> in quotes like "<:]{%>"

Comment: Probably it triggers an implicit conversion to a non-null pointer to function and is printed as a boolean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15736295/241631) to the question you've linked to,

```
<:]{%>
```

is equivalent to

```
[]{}
```

A lambda expression that doesn't capture anything is implicitly convertible to a function pointer. In this case, the signature of this function pointer is `void(*)()`.

Now, the function pointer is [implicitly convertible to a boolean value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18889969/241631) which is always `true`, hence the output prints `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put " around <:]{%>.

You should have :

```
std::cout << "<:]{%>";
```