# Meaning of "([&]()" (Threading in C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I found this code on https://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2013/spring/12300-1/labs/lab6/ where the producer-consumer problem is explained. What is the meaning of `([&]()`? Below is a section of the code, where the syntax is used.

```
thread reporter([&]() {
    /*
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
    while (!notified) {
        cond_var.wait(lock);
    }
    */
    cout << "The value is " << value << endl;
});
```

Comment: [&](){...} is a lambda expression/function.

Comment: @SagunKho So is `<:]{%>`, but I don't think putting answers in comments is ideal.

Comment: @Yakk in what language?

Comment: @SagunKho C++: [What is this smiley-with-beard expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736282/what-is-this-smiley-with-beard-expression)